# How to pass a variable to function-lambda-expression

Tags: function, common-lisp

Let's say you want to get the lambda list of every function in a package. On SBCL, using `iterate` you could do this

```lisp
(use-package :iterate)

(defun lambda-lists (package)
  (iter (for symbol in-package (find-package package))
        (collect (sb-introspect:function-type symbol))))
```

To be more portable you might try something like this

```lisp
(defun lambda-lists (package)
  (iter (for symbol in-package (find-package package))
        (collect (function-lambda-expression symbol))))
```

But this won't work since `function-lambda-expression` takes a function, not a symbol.
Something like `(function symbol)` won't work either since it makes a function called `symbol`, not a function called the value of `symbol`.

Is there a way to realize this with macro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to find out which symbol denotes a global function and not a macro or special form. See: [FBOUNDP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fbound.htm#fboundp), [MACRO-FUNCTION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_macro_.htm#macro-function), [SPECIAL-OPERATOR-P](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_specia.htm#special-operator-p)

Then you need to retrieve the function from the symbol: use [SYMBOL-FUNCTION](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_1.htm#symbol-function).